# Sequelize - Foreign key that references same table primary key

Tags: sequelize.js

Is it possible to construct the following in Sequelize model syntax? The use being you want to have nested data.

```
CREATE TABLE Data
(
    `id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ...
    `parentId` INT,
    FOREIGN KEY(parentId) REFERENCES Data(id)
);
```

**EDIT: Yes it is**

```
const Data = sequelize.define('Data', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
    },
})

Data.belongsTo(Data, { foreignKey: 'id' });
```

Answer (score 5):

It appears you can!

```
const Data = sequelize.define('Data', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
    },
})

Data.belongsTo(Data, { foreignKey: 'id' });
```