# Async await result

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

Currently in a professional transition, I'm working on a study project where I have to create a kind of mini forum. I used node.js/express and sequelize for my database.
In the code bellow, my API try to retrieve 10 last messages (with pagination stuff) to send to my welcome page. It perfectly works. The problem is that some messages have a null title because they are just answers of other messages. I'd like to change this null title by the parent_id_msg title I saved into db.

But because of async code, I receive promise object and I can't use it into my synchronous code (resulting of an undefined title at the end). After reading many ressources and trying some solutions for the last 3 days, I thinks I understand the problem about async/await used with sync code, but I still don't understand how to override it and progress.

PS : I'm not sure of my "async list" but I don't know where to put async :(

```
    exports.lastsMessages = (req, res, next) => {
    //find 10 last messages (responses includes)
    let answer = {
        count : 0,
        list:[]
    };
    let tmp;
    Message.findAndCountAll({
        order:[['creation_date', 'DESC']],
        offset: 10 * req.body.pageNbr - 10,
        limit: 10
    })
        .then( async list=>{
                answer.count = list.count;
                for(let i = 0; i<list.rows.length;i++){
                    tmp = list.rows[i].dataValues;
                    if(tmp.title === null || tmp.title === ""){
                        console.log('before'+ tmp.title) // output NULL as expected
                        tmp.title =   await findTitle(tmp.parent_msg_id);
                        console.log('after '+ tmp.title)// output undefined, not as expected :(
                    }
                    answer.list.push(tmp)
                };
            res.status(200).json({...answer, message:'10 derniers messages'})
        })
        .catch(error => res.status(400).json({error, message:'Messages non récupérés'}));     
  };
  async function findTitle(parentId){
    Message.findOne(
        {attributes:['title'], 
        where:{id:parentId}})
        .then(potatoes=> {
            console.log('inside '+ potatoes.dataValues.title)
            //output parent message title inside function, as excepted
            return potatoes.dataValues.title});
 };
```

Thank you in advance (and sorry as beginner for potential mistakes, misunderstanding and english level)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning anything from findTitle.

Try this on the first line of the findTitle function:

```
return Message.findOne(...
```

Also the findTitle function does not need to be async because you are not using await inside it. As another aside, it's generally a bad idea to use await inside loops.

Comment: First Alex, thank you for your quick answer, it's very helpfull. If I remove the async, then I have to remove all await and async above. If I do that and return Message.findOne(), I don't receive undefine anymore but an empty object. I think findOne is async method of sequelize so I keep the async and await and I finally have the good result in my display

Comment: But with this solution, I have to  "await" into a loop, and I trust you if you say it's a bad idea. How can I improve the code?

Comment: When I said "findTitle does not need to be async", I just meant that the function does not need to be defined as async because you are not using await inside it. For example, this: "async function findTitle(parentId){" can be changed to: "function findTitle(parentId){"

As for the async within the loop issue, the solution depends on what you are trying to acheive as well as your database structure. The cleanest way would be to add a ref to the parent document, which you can then populate, rather than perform two queries. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: I'd suggest adding a ref property to the message model (which might not be needed in some cases, but that's fine), which you can then populate. Once it is populated, you can call message.parent.dataValues.title to get the title of the parent document. This would mean you do not have to perform another query to get the parent title as it would already be populated on the existing message under the "parent" property.

Comment: Sorry, just seen that you are using Sequelize. Here is a link to their docs regarding foreign keys and population: https://sequelize.org/v3/docs/associations/

Comment: Thanks. For foreign keys, it was an option. I had put it aside because I didn't master it enough but it's the better way, for sure. The message model is the same for messages and responses (with a parent_msg_id at null or not), so I have to place a foreign key in a model, linked to himself, I don't know if it's recommanded, I'll try to do it without destroying the space-time continuum ;)

Comment: Should have no issues with an association to the same table. That is a perfectly acceptable approach. This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50656007/sequelize-foreign-key-that-references-same-table-primary-key